# IIS7 localhost default location troubles

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis-7, localhost

new member here and am stuck with an IIS7 issue. I'm running Windows Server 2008 with IIS7 and my sites are located under C:\inetpub\wwwroot. I have a few sites running with host headers on there but my problem is that when I type in the IP to the server it takes me into a sub directory of the wwwroot folder.

So when I type in the ip address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx into a browser it's supposed to take me to the wwwroot directory which has the welcome splash page for IIS7; instead it takes me directly into a site (wwwroot/mysite/). Any ideas on how to change this back?

Comment: Have you checked the `Pysical path` for the `Default Web Site` ?

Comment: yes, the physical path for the Dafault site is correct at %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot

Comment: hmmm... In that case my guess is that you have a duplicate binding : same ip for the Default Web Site and for another site that **does not have** a Host Header defined. Can you check this ?

Comment: Hmm.. you were right in the fact that the site in question which it was defaulting to had a double binding of port 80 with no host header just like Default Web Site. I removed it and added a host header; site still works fine.

Only now when I type in the IP or do a http://localhost/ in the browser I get a 404. Any ideas on how I can go about checking where exactly the IP is trying to pull from?

Comment: First, ensure you have a Host Header defined for each Web Sites (except the default one), then check for the default document defined for the Default site and ensure that file exists in the specified root folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have a duplicate binding : 
the same IP is used for the `Default Web Site` and for another Site that does **NOT** have a Host Header defined.

My advice : Check for a Web Site where you don't have defined a Host Header and
   define one.

Comment: This was definitely it; thank you for the help! I was getting a 404 after fixing the bindings b/c I noticed that the Default Web Site was stopped and couldn't be restarted due to SSL conflict. Got it all fixed up now. Thanks again.